# Anaconda Pycharm throws ImportError DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found : solved

Tags: python, importerror

I am using Anaconda and PyCharm, where import numpy returns ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

As of now I have added below paths to the PATH user variable, which has resolved the issue temporarily.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib;
```

is there any better solution there ?

Comment: have you set the python interpreter?

Comment: Can you import the same module when you start python.exe from the conda prompt?  I am having the same issue, I guess python is not adding the paths to the conda libraries. Works well with Spyder & conda prompt, but in Pycharm and windows cmd the problems start. For me it looks like your solution is the only one right now (I think adding ...\Anaconda3\Library\bin; is actually sufficient). But I am not sure if this is a nice way when you start working with environments other than the base environment.